# Get .phtml file path in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url, view.phtml

I would like to get the location of the **.phtml** file of this URL `https://chaldal.com/sales/order/print/order_id/13/` of Magento2.

Answer (score 3):

As you check the layout file **vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_print.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\PrintShipment" name="sales.order.print" template="order/view.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\PrintShipment" name="order_items" template="order/items.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="sales.order.print.renderers" as="renderer.list" />
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals" name="order_totals" template="order/totals.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label_properties" xsi:type="string">colspan="4" class="mark"</argument>
                            <argument name="value_properties" xsi:type="string">class="amount"</argument>
                        </arguments>
                        <block class="Magento\Tax\Block\Sales\Order\Tax" name="tax" template="order/tax.phtml">
                            <action method="setIsPlaneMode">
                                <argument name="value" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                            </action>
                        </block>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info" as="sales.order.print.info" name="sales.order.print.info" template="order/info.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
```

Template file **vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/template/order/view.phtml**

Comment: Thanks @Qaisar Satti for your reply. But I am getting more than these .xml and .phtml files. I am getting extra Header and footer also.

Comment: @abuabu use these  layout handle also `<update handle="sales_order_print_renderers" />
    <update handle="sales_order_item_price"/>
    <update handle="print" />`

Comment: Thanks @Qaisar Satti for your reply. But What does it mean ?

Comment: I am getting these also `/app/design/frontend/Alothemes/default/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml` and `app/design/frontend/Alothemes/default/Magiccart_Magicproduct/templates/productcustom.phtml`.

Comment: @abuabu it mean predefined layout like account page layout if you are familiar with that  i think in your case single `<update handle="print" />` will do

Comment: How can I remove `/app/design/frontend/Alothemes/default/Magento_Theme/templat‌​es/html/header.phtml` and `app/design/frontend/Alothemes/default/Magiccart_Magicproduct‌​/templates/productcu‌​stom.phtml`? Thanks

Comment: @abuabu use this `<referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true"/>`
        `<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true"/>`

Comment: Thanks @Qaisar Satti . But where should I use this and how to use this ? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68748/discussion-between-qaisar-satti-and-abu-abu).